# Add ADO.NET data tables to a blank MDB file

Tags: .net, ms-access, ado.net, datatable, dataset

How can I add several data tables that I've built in code, to a blank MDB file that ships with my application?

I find it easy enough to connect to the MDB file via the OledbConnection object, but then I'm at a loss for an easy way to add my tables to it. There it sits, open and empty, but what is next?

I can add my tables to a dataset easily enough, but I still don't see an easy way to map the dataset over to my open MDB file.

Am I missing an easy fix for this? I'd like to avoid using [ADOX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms803875) if possible. I also see that it is very easy to write the dataset out as XML, but I find no similar functionality for writing out an MDB file.

Comment: Are you wanting to create new tables in the MDB file or are you just trying to copy changes made in the local dataset back to the database MDB file?

Comment: They are new tables...I have a few functions that set them up and fill them with data, and return a datatable object for each table. I can then create a dataset and add the tables to it. So far, so good.

The blank database is exactly that, completely blank. I want to fill it with my tables.

Comment: gotcha. Is there a reason why the database has to be shipped blank? I am guessing that there is, because that would solve some problems for you.

Comment: That's a good question for the client that I'm doing this work for. I think that it's a legacy thing that he's done before, but that would have been in the ADO world, not .NET. It seems like it would make more sense to ship the MDB empty, but with the tables in it. That would make everything easier.

Answer (score 0):

DataSet intrinsically understands the XML storage, you might think of it (very loosely mind) as its native data store.  In fact XML storage is meant for temporary or transistory storage so that a DataSet can be re-constituted between application re-starts or transference between machines.

On the other hand, true persistence stores such as MDB, SQL Server, Oracle or whatever are entirely alien to the Dataset, that's why you need provider specific Adapters to transfer data to and from the Dataset.

Unless you can find a project out in web-land where someone has done this before you are going to need to create your own code to analyse the dataset schema then send DDL to you MDB connection to create the tables.